# PassportJS Facebook Strategy, nodejs & angular running on diffrent servers

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, mean-stack

probleme when calling nodejs(localhost:3000)passport facebook stratrgy authentification from "another server" angular(localhost:8080).

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https:/www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&client_id=154021398315208. Redirect from 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&client_id=154021398315208' to 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=154021398315208…_&display=page&locale=en_US&logger_id=91549505-c21b-1176-243b-5cc5e73a788a' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a couple of issues.

In your Facebook App settings you may have to authorize localhost as a valid App Domain.

Secondly, since your requests are cross domain you may have to tweak web security while in localhost.

The browser is blocking these requests since you are on one website, but calling API's on another. This is a simple way hackers hack your users so most browsers block it. [Here's a quick tutorial on CORS.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)